# How to get a specific string out of a database with C# using a parameter that can change in layer model

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I need to make a helpdesk form for my end of year task and I'm stuck.

The task requires me to load the solution of a specific problem that the user selects via a `combobox`. My implementation needs to separated into layers like business persist and so on.

The code that I wrote to solve this didn't work (*EXPLAIN WHY HERE*). I have made a few attempts at it and have included them below.

**First Attempt:**

For my first attempt, I have written the following code to load the solution to the selected problem from the database:

```
public List<HelpDesk> getOplossing()
{
    List<HelpDesk> lijst = new List<HelpDesk>();
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(_connectionstring);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Oplosing from tblhelpdesk where Probleem = @probleem" , conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@probleem",                     
    getProbleem().ToString()));

    conn.Open();
    MySqlDataReader datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (datareader.Read())
    {
        HelpDesk hlpdsk = new HelpDesk(
           datareader["Oplosing"].ToString());
        lijst.Add(hlpdsk);

    }
    conn.Close();
    return lijst;
}
```

And in the controller I called it like this:

```
public List<HelpDesk> getOplossing()
{
    return _persistcode.getOplossing();
}
```

**Attempt 2:**

This is what I wrote for my second attempt.

```
public string getOplossing()
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(_connectionstring);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Oplosing from tblhelpdesk", conn);
    conn.Open();
    string oplossing;
    oplossing = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    conn.Close();
    return oplossing;
}
```

Again in the controller:

```
public string getOplossing()
{
    return _persistcode.getOplossing();
}
```

**My entire HelpDesk class:**

And the class `HelpDesk` looks like this: (I provided the whole class so you guys can have a gander at all the problem :/ )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GPDeBruykerSander_Domain.Business
{
    public class HelpDesk
    {
        private int _id;
        private Boolean _categorie; //Hardware= True en Software= False
        private DateTime _datumProbleem;
        private string _probleem;
        private DateTime _datumOplossing;
        private string _oplossing; 

        public int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Probleem;
        }

        public Boolean Categorie
        {
            get { return _categorie; }
            set { _categorie = value; }
        }

        public DateTime DatumProbleem
        {
            get { return _datumProbleem; }
            set { _datumProbleem = value; }
        }

        public string Probleem
        {
            get { return _probleem; }
            set { _probleem = value; }
        }

        public DateTime DatumOplossing
        {
            get { return _datumOplossing; }
            set { _datumOplossing = value; }
        }

        public string Oplossing
        {
            get { return _oplossing; }
            set { _oplossing = value; }
        }

        public HelpDesk (int id, Boolean categorie, DateTime datumProbleem, string probleem, DateTime datumOplossing, string oplossing)
        {
            _id = id;
            _categorie = categorie;
            _datumProbleem = datumProbleem;
            _probleem = probleem;
            _datumOplossing = datumOplossing;
            _oplossing = oplossing;
        }

        public HelpDesk(Boolean categorie, DateTime datumProbleem, string probleem, DateTime datumOplossing, string oplossing)
        {
            _categorie = categorie;
            _datumProbleem = datumProbleem;
            _probleem = probleem;
            _datumOplossing = datumOplossing;
            _oplossing = oplossing;
        }
        public HelpDesk(DateTime datumProbleem, Boolean categorie, string probleem)
        {
            _datumProbleem = datumProbleem;
            _categorie = categorie;
            _probleem = probleem;

        }
        public HelpDesk(DateTime datumOplossing, string oplossing)
        {
            _datumOplossing = datumOplossing;
            _oplossing = oplossing;       
        }

        public HelpDesk(string probleem)
        {
            _probleem = probleem;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope somebody can help me find the solution because I'm stuck :/

Answer (score 0):

You were closer to solving your problem in your first attempt, so I will help you with that. But since you haven't actually provided any reasons as to why your code doesn't work (errors thrown by the application, etc.), I can only take a stab at potential issues I see in your code.

Looking at your MySQL query: `SELECT Oplosing from tblhelpdesk where Probleem = @probleem`, I would say that you are missing quotes around `@probleem`. So this query should look like this:

```
SELECT Oplosing from tblhelpdesk where Probleem = '@probleem'
```

I would also make the following suggestions:

**Suggestion 1**: Make `getProbleem()` method actually return a `string`, so you don't have to call `ToString()` on it. You haven't provided the implementation of this method so I can only assume the return type is not a `string`. If the return type is a `string` the `ToString()` is completely redundant here.

**Suggestion 2:**
I would also suggestion is that you pass the problem string as a parameter to `getOplossing()`, so that the database code is encapsulated better. For example:

```
public List<HelpDesk> getOplossing(string probleem)
{
    ...

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@probleem", probleem));

    ...
}
```

And your controller will call it like so:

```
public List<HelpDesk> getOplossing()
{
    string probleem = getProbleem().ToString();

    return _persistcode.getOplossing(probleem);
}
```